# What might cause Google People details to stop syncing?

Tags: sync, google-account

I'm having difficulty troubleshooting Google failing to sync "People details". All other categories (contacts, email, etc.) are syncing properly.

[image: Google sync is currently experiencing problems]

This is causing downstream issues in other apps. For example, I can't review businesses in Google Maps because it wants me to "Add your name to your Google account", which I've already tried to set and reset.

I am fairly certain this may be a permissions issue somewhere but I can't seem to track it down. **Does anyone have any general advice on how to troubleshoot this issue?** Thank you.

Device: OnePlus 3T
Android version: 8.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, tried several solutions but the only one that worked was resetting the phone to factory settings.